# Finding a suitable axis-angle to avoid gimbal lock

Tags: opengl, camera, matrix, rotation, quaternion

In OpenGL the camera faces the -z axis with the +y axis pointing up. I am using quaternions to represent the orientation of my objects (which works well) and am trying to do the same for the camera. I want the camera's initial orientation rotation to face the +x axis with the up vector being +z. I was attempting to initialize the camera's quaternion rotation by multiplying two 90 degree rotation quaternions in an effort to achieve this, but I believe I am experiencing gimbal lock because I cannot orient the camera properly (the first rotation works fine, the second one produces undesired results). I haven't been able to wrap my head around an axis-angle representation that will orient the camera the way I want.

In summary:

I'm searching for an axis angle (or anything that can be converted to a quaternion really) that will provide the following rotation:

inital camera orientation: facing -z axis, +y pointing up

desired orientation: facing +x axis, +z pointing up

Note: I am already aware of gluLookAt, this problem was my attempt at understanding more about how everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orientation you are looking for is:

```
Rotation Axis : 0.577, -0.577, -0.577
Rotation Angle: 2.094 radians or 120.0 degrees
```

The quaternion that represents that orientation is:

```
q: 0.500, -0.500, -0.500, 0.500
```

where the first 3 terms are the imaginary part (the rotation axis) and the last term commonly known as w, the encoded rotation angle.

Following is the code I used to calculate the orienation. If you don't have a linear algebra library yet, this is the point where you either want to roll your own or to download one. [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/) for instance.

Now back to the calculation. The first orientation frame you describe is basically the identity matrix for the opengl camera (facing -z axis, +y pointing up).
The second orientation frame is our target orientation: facing +x axis, +z pointing up. Calculating the matrix from those 2 parameters is pretty straight forward, the following function is an example how to do it:

```
void gm33GetOrientationMatrix(
        matrix33 result,
        vector3 const dir,
        vector3 const up )
{
    gv3CopyNegated( result[2], dir );
    gv3CrossProduct( result[0], up, result[2] );
    gv3Normalize( result[0] );
    gv3CrossProduct( result[1], result[2], result[0] );
}
```

Once we have this matrix, its pretty simple to calculate a quaternion from it, [here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/) you can find the code for the matrix-quaternion conversion.

And voila, that's it, we have the quaternion. As an example, here is the full code I used to calculate it:

```
// calculate our target rotation matrix
vector3 target_dir = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
vector3 target_up = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
matrix33 target;
gm33GetOrientationMatrix( target, target_dir, target_up );

// convert it to a quaternion
quaternion rot;
gqFromM33( rot, target );
```

Comment: I plugged in your axis-angle values directly but I didn't not get the proper rotation. I then tried plugging in your quaternion directly and got the same matrix (which didn't work). I am using functions built into LWJGL (OpenGL for Java). I ended up creating a matrix by hand using the source code of gluLook
At. The working matrix for my desired orientation is (row by row) [0 -1 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [ -1 0 0 0] [0 0 0 1]. The matrix calculated from your values is [2.28E-4 2.28E-4 1 0] [-1 2.28E-4 2.28E-4 0] [-2.28E-4 -1 2.28E-4 0] [0 0 0 1] ... any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Well I converted the matrix that I calculated to a quaternion, and then converted that to an axis angle, and the values for the quat and axis-angle match what you specified. So I know now that your answer is correct, and I messed up somewhere in the process of multiplying the matrix with a translation matrix, and inverting the whole thing to load into the modelview matrix.

Comment: Finally I'd like to mention that what I have now (its working) is to take the quaternion rotation, and generate the matrix using a method I found here [link](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToMatrix/jay.htm). I must have been doing something wrong with the LWJGL functions. I create the matrix from the quaternion, multiply a translation matrix to it, and invert result. The information to calculate the quaternion orientation is indeed very useful, however all I needed was the initial rotation for the camera (which I can simply hardcode into the game).